# Access crashes when running update Querys

Tags: ms-access, odbc

Ok so I have some VBA that I have written and it worked fine in Windows 7, but when we upgraded to Windows 10 it stopped working.  Every time the code is executed it crashes Access.  It is just a simple update statement to a database that I have an ODBC link to.  I have done some testing and any time I try to use an updated Query that I have any type of external join my access crashes.  For example my Oracle table name is "SerialNumber" and my Access table is named “Sheet1” they are joined on a field named “SerialNumber.Number” to “Sheet1.AM1id”.  I can view the data and everything looks ok.  When I try to update a value in the “SerialNumber” table Access crashes. I have two computers connected to the same network.  The Windows 10 computer crashes every time.  The Windows 7 computer works every time.

Comment: This is not really a programming issue. Perhaps try uninstall/reinstall Access. Maybe a newer ODBC driver.

Comment: not enough information.  One possibility is the odbc connection needs to be set up again: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/administer-odbc-data-sources-b19f856b-5b9b-48c9-8b93-07484bfab5a7